# Cannot figure out how to use mount command on MacOS

Tags: macos, mount, automount, docker

I am trying to use mount as in `man mount`, on MacOS. Ultimately, what I am trying to do is mount a directory which is outside of the Docker build context and put the directory inside the Docker build context. Apparently symlinks do not work, and so I am trying to do this with the mount command. (If you know of a better way, pls lmk).

So I have this:

```
mkdir -p "$(pwd)/some_local_dir"
mount -t auto "${project_root}" "$(pwd)/some_local_dir"
```

which is attempting to mount the project into a local directory

I get this error:

> mount: exec /Library/Filesystems/auto.fs/Contents/Resources/mount_auto
>   for /Users/alexamil/test/some_local_dir: No such file or directory

I tried deleting the directory, and not calling mkdir -p, and same problem. Super weird.

Anyone know what might be wrong with my `mount` command?

Comment: Only the _root_ user can mount a filesystem with the `mount` command in macOS, so preface it with `sudo`, e.g. `sudo mount ...`. Also, read the manual page: "The argument following the **−t** is used to indicate the file system type. There is no default local file system for use with mount. A type must be specified in order to mount a non-NFS filesystem."  So I take that to be you actually have to specify the filesystem type, not use _auto_.

Comment: thanks, apparently (according to docs somewhere) "auto" is a filesystem type, where mount will try to automatically determine your fs type.

Comment: Let me rephrase that, since using `-t auto` with the `mount` command under macOS is throwing an error, use the actual formatted filesystem type of the device being mounted, instead.

Comment: yeah I will try that, still seems like a bad error that's thrown from the command line parser.